# iOS - UIView above UITabBar with Layout Guide

Tags: ios, uiview, uitabbar, uilayoutguide

I have a UIView above my UITabBar that will be able to show and disappear. The View is added as a SubView in the UITabBarController's View. I want to change the Bottom Layout Guide depending on the View's state.

**Example:**
When the View is hidden, the Bottom Layout Guide is animated to the TabBarController's default. When the View is visible, the Bottom Layout Guide animates to the TabBar's height + the height of the View above the TabBar.

How can I achieve that?

[image: An example of what I am making.]

Comment: can you explain a bit more in detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I edited the question, is this detailed enough?

Comment: The cleanest way imho is to create a custom viewcontroller with a containerview, your toggleable view and a tabbar.

Comment: The bottom distance + the View's height becomes the bottom layout guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result I wanted can be achieved in iOS 11 by using the additionalSafeAreaInsets on the desired ViewController.

```
viewController.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, offsetFromBottom, 0)
```

If you want to animate the elements adapting to the updated insets add this code along with the updated insets to your animation block.

```
viewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Could you share how you accomplished this so that it is more useful to others? Sometimes a picture is worth 1000 words. +1 for your efforts.

Comment: I added the code, let me know if this works for you.

Comment: UIEdgeInsets don't have a UIView as a property, so the second line is not correct. The first is more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, the second line is used to animate objects inside an animation block.